# Calculating percent of time remaining from two dates

Tags: php, time, percentage

So far im trying to get the percentage of time remaining between two dates so i can use a progress bar..

I have the following code i'm passing in two dates and doing the sum but i am getting an error. i'm not sure if this error is because of the date format if so i can change it.

```
<?
$start = '2015-11-03 14:05:15';
$end = '2015-11-03 18:05:15';

$current = '2015-11-03 16:12:15';

$completed = (($current - $start) / ($end - $start)) * 100;

?>

<? print $completed; ?>
```

I am getting the following error.
Warning: Division by zero

Comment: You can't substract strings like that. You should use for example a timestamp, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 3):

strtotime will take a date string and turn it into unix standard time as seconds.

```
<?
$start = strtotime('2015-11-03 14:05:15');
$end = strtotime('2015-11-03 18:05:15');

$current = strtotime('2015-11-03 16:12:15');

$completed = (($current - $start) / ($end - $start)) * 100;

?>

<? print $completed; ?>
```

Comment: Brilliant, Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

You're using strings (basically, plain text)... So you can't calculate anything.
You should use timestamps for that (miliseconds since start of 1970)

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strtotime.php

```
$start = strtotime('2015-11-03 14:05:15');
$end = strtotime('2015-11-03 18:05:15');
$current = strtotime('2015-11-03 16:12:15');
```

Comment: Brilliant, Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the DateTime object over strtotime. DateTime allows you to specify the format that creates the timestamp, instead of relying on strtotime to magically figure it out. This makes it far more reliable.

For example:

```
<?php
$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2015-11-03 14:05:15');
$end = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2015-11-03 18:05:15');
$current = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2015-11-03 16:12:15');
$completed = (($current->getTimestamp() - $start->getTimestamp()) / ($end->getTimestamp() - $start->getTimestamp())) * 100;
echo $completed; 
?>
```

Note: DateTime objects were introduced in PHP 5.3. Any older versions will not have DateTime. (and quite honestly, should be updated for many reasons)

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. the code gives an error on line 2.. Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::createFromFormat()

Comment: @LiamArmour DateTime::createFromFormat() was introduced in PHP 5.3. And most likely you have older version of PHP. So - installing PHP >= 5.3 will cause this to work, otherwise you're stuck with strtotime() :)

Comment: Brilliant, Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Those are strings. You can't subtract strings and expect things to work. What's happening is this:

```
$start = '2015-11-03 14:05:15';
$end = '2015-11-03 18:05:15';
```

Since you're doing `-`, PHP converts those strings to integers:

```
$new_start = (int)$start; // 2015
$new_end = (int)$end; // 2015

$new_end - $new_start -> 0
```

YOu need to `strtotime()` those values back into a unix timestamp, and then you **CAN** subtract those values, and get a difference in seconds.

Comment: Brilliant, Thanks alot.